# Battery Charging status c#

Tags: c#

What's the simplest way possible to get the state/status of a battery charging in c#? I'm not looking for % I'm just looking for a really simple way to get whether or not the battery is charging.

Comment: what device are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify if you are using WinForms or WPF. But this is the simplest way I can think of: `SystemInformation.PowerStatus.BatteryChargeStatus`

There's a lot of useful system information in SystemInformation. It requires you to add an import to `System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation`

Comment: So I can use this in WPF?

Comment: Yeah this works in WPF. You'll just have to add a reference in your project.